# Stack images vertically and center

Tags: imagemagick

I have several images of different widths and heights that I would like to stack vertically about their respective centers.
I've tried

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -append out.jpg
```

But this aligns them to the left, I'd like it to be center-aligned.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Incorporate usage of the [gravity](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) ImageMagick command line option as in the below examples.

### Side by side

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -gravity center +append out.jpg
```

### Stacked (one on top of the other)

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -gravity center -append out.jpg
```

Additionally, you might also consider using the [resize](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) ImageMagick command line options to scale the pictures up in size to use more of the page.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Gravity](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity)
- [Resize](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize)